# Why doesn't while ''IFS=, read -r part'' split a comma-separated string into two parts?

Tags: bash, unix, ifs

since the default value of the IFS variable is a newline/tab/space, the following code:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
done <<< "hello\nworld"
```

outputs:

```
hello
world
```

---

but, if I understand it correctly, I can change it so it will separate it by, comma for example.

so this code:

```
while IFS=',' read -r part
do
    echo $part
done <<< "hello,world"
```

but this one just outputs:

```
hello,world
```

and I expected it to print the same as the script from before.

what am I missing here?

Comment: `help read` : "Read a line from the standard input [...] The line is split into fields [...] with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME"

Comment: `read` is only populating one variable, so no splitting occurs. That said, your first loop should only output `hello\nworld`. Your input string is one line containing the two characters ``\`` and `n`, not two lines.

Comment: @chepner, smells like the OP is running somewhere `echo` has XPG-like behavior and is replacing the `\n` with a newline itself (which is odd, because that's very much not default on bash).

Comment: @yoyobara, ...are you starting your script with `#!/bin/bash` or running it with `bash yourscript`? If your interpreter were something other than bash (for example, if it were `sh`), that would clear up the mystery about `echo` behavior.

Answer (score 6):

#### Answering The "Why" Question

IFS is a *field* separator, not a *record* separator. (The default record separator is the newline; it can be changed with the `-d` argument to `read`). Each call to `read` reads a single record, and optionally splits it into multiple variables at field boundaries.

When you run `read -r part`, you're reading only one record (the one that goes into `part`), so there's no separating to be done: it's thus normal and expected that `$part` contains the entire record, commas included.

---

#### Alternatives Where IFS *Is* Honored

By contrast, if you used `-a` to specify your destination as an array (`read -r -a parts`) or passed more than one destination variable (`read -r part1 part2 part3`), splitting into fields would take place.

Compare to:

```
while IFS=, read -r key value; do
  echo "key=$key, value=$value"
done <<EOF
hello,world
hi,neighbor
EOF
```

Similarly, one can read a line into an array:

```
while IFS=, read -r -a parts; do          # split on comma into array
  printf 'Read %d parts: ' "${#parts[@]}" # count items in array
  printf '<%s> ' "${parts[@]}"            # print those items in arrow brackets
  printf '\n'
done <<EOF
three,word,array
this,is,four,words
EOF
```

...which, as expected, emits:

```
Read 3 parts: <three> <word> <array> 
Read 4 parts: <this> <is> <four> <words>
```